# Value nil when changing String to Date after retrieving from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, date, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored a Date value as String in my Firebase Database since Firebase doesn't allow you to store it as a Date data type. Here is a screenshot of the Database:

[image: Firebase database]

There is no issue with the retrieval of the data. After retrieving, I want to convert the String to Date ("10-22-2019 22:12"), here is the code:

```
class CustomNotificationsTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var notificationTableCellData: NotificationsData? {
        didSet {

            let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
            let deadline = dateformatter.date(from: notificationTableData.storyDeadline) // notificationTableData.storyDeadline is the date String

            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in

                let seconds = Int(deadline?.timeIntervalSinceNow ?? 0.0)
                self.timeLeft.text = "\(seconds / 3600):\((seconds % 3600) / 60):\(seconds % 60)"

                if seconds == 0 {
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the value of the variable `deadline` is always nil; how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set date format to your dateformatter before obtaining date from string. Assuming your Due Date (10-22-2019 22:12) is the input, dateFormat would be as follows.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
```

Comment: make sure to set your date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` when parsing fixed date formats. Btw regarding OP original pos, as it is, it will create a new date formatter every time it creates a new cell.